# How to install cairo on Windows

Tags: haskell, cairo, cabal

For the life of me I can't figure out how to install cairo on Windows!

I need it for [Haskell Charts](http://dockerz.net/twd/HaskellCharts), but when I follow setup instructions and get to running:

```
cabal install gtk
```

I get this error:

```
Linking dist/setup-wrapper\setup.exe ...
Configuring glib-0.12.2...
setup.exe: The program pkg-config version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
be found.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.12.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gio-0.12.2 depends on glib-0.12.2 which failed to install.
glib-0.12.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gtk-0.12.2 depends on glib-0.12.2 which failed to install.
pango-0.12.2 depends on glib-0.12.2 which failed to install.
```

If I go to [cairo site](http://cairographics.org/download/), they don't have anywhere any kind of setup. Just a bunch of dlls that I don't know what to do with (how to make Haskell see them).

Any help appreciated, as I've been trying to install the damn thing for hours!

Comment: The error seems pretty clear (it's in the third line above): "setup.exe: The program pkg-config version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found".

Comment: I think that route of installation requires a whole building environment. The DLL usage sounds easy "Just pop libcairo-2.dll, libpng13.dll and zlib1.dll into your working directory or system PATH" (from the cairo page you've linked).

Answer (score 5):

You need to download the all-in-one bundle available [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip). You can discover this link yourself by visiting http://www.gtk.org/ and clicking "Download", then "Windows (32-bit)". Extract it to a directory that doesn't include spaces, and add that directory to your PATH. You will also need to `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools` before you attempt to `cabal install gtk`.

These instructions can also be found [on the gtk2hs website](http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/INSTALL).

Comment: I get a little further this time - I manage to install `gtk`! But when I run `cabal install chart` I still get: `Loading package cairo-0.12.2 ... linking ... ghc.exe: C:\Users\drozzy\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.2\ghc-7.0.4\HScai
ro-0.12.2.o: unknown symbol '_cairo_image_surface_get_data'
ghc.exe: unable to load package 'cairo-0.12.2'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
Chart-0.15 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1`

Answer (score 1):

Since the answers on this page have been posted, GTK has stopped publishing Windows binaries. A third party compiles up-to-date `dll`s here: http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm

Comment: Hm, I don't think it's that the GTK people have stopped supporting Windows or something. They still have [a download page for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php), it just recommends that MSYS2 is used. Which, I reckon, makes a lot of sense and is easier than manually installing dll files.

Comment: It looks like they've moved the Windows installation page mentioned by @leftaroundabout to here: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you might need to do

`cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools`

before you can install `gtk` itself.

Comment: Did that. My problem was I didn't place the link to gtk `bin` directory in my path. However, now I am encountering another problem. See my comment on @Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[The 64-bit GTK3 installer](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases) worked for me. In the installer, I kept the "Set up PATH environment variable" checkbox checked, as recommended in [this otherwise outdated guide](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows).

Not important: Before that, I tried [the 32-bit GTK2 installer](https://gtk-win.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Main/Downloads) as recommended in [the cairocffi documentation under "Installing cairo on Windows"](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows), but that resulted in `cannot load library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1`, and then I found [this WeasyPrint issue](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/957) (WeasyPrint apparently uses cairo and is from the same company as cairocffi and CairoSVG), which led me to [the documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows), which links to the 64-bit version linked above.