# Installing Cairo, Helm on Windows

Tags: cairo, cabal-install

How do I install Helm (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/helm) on Windows 7 (64-bit)?

(Update: I had posted a lot of error messages here, but I've moved them to my answer to not clutter up the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation for Windows 64-bit:

I'm including error messages, for if you follow all the steps up to that point and then just try to install directly. This is a conglomeration of a bunch of ad-hoc steps from following many different posts. Any simplification would be appreciated!

Note: Do all work in directories without spaces. I'm doing all work in C:/PF; modify this to your directory.

1. Download MSYS2-x86_64 from https://msys2.github.io/ and install it. Cabal install cairo (or helm) will give something like:

   Configuring cairo-0.13.1.0...
     setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:

   - Missing C libraries: z, cairo, z, gobject-2.0, ffi, pixman-1, fontconfig,
     expat, freetype, iconv, expat, freetype, z, bz2, harfbuzz, glib-2.0, intl,
     ws2_32, ole32, winmm, shlwapi, intl, png16, z
2. Download C libraries. In MINGW64 (NOT MSYS2 - I had trouble with MSYS2 at random stages in the process), use the package manager:

   pacman -Ss cairo

to search for the Cairo package. You'll find  "mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo", so install that:

```
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo
```

*.pc files should have been added to C:\PF\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig and C:\PF\msys64\usr\lib\pkgconfig. (pkg-config needs to be able to find these files. It looks in PKG_CONFIG_PATH, which by default should have the lib/pkgconfig folder above. Moving the file here is easiest. See [Can't install sdl2 via cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713200/cant-install-sdl2-via-cabal)) If you get

```
The pkg-config package ... version ... cannot be found
```

errors then check your *.pc files.

Repeat with other required libraries, like atk

```
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-atk
```

(I don't know the complete list, but error messages later on will let you know what to get.)

3. Get the development files for these libraries (as suggested by [How to install cairo on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526375/how-to-install-cairo-on-windows)). Most of them are bundled up at http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/gtk+/2.22/. Unzip.

   - Copy files (.a, .dll.a) in lib to C:\PF\msys64\mingw64\lib. Copy the pkgconfig folder, which contains the .pc files.
   - Copy files in include to C:\PF\msys64\mingw64\include.
   - Add C:\PF\gtk+-2.22.1\bin to the path.

(2) and (3) might be redundant. I don't know - I did them both.

At this point you can probably do "cabal install cairo". (Warning: if your end goal is something else, you may not want to "cabal install" intermediate packages, see https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/Survival#Issue_.232_--_Not_installing_all_the_packages_in_one_go.) 
See (4) for the syntax in specifying extra-include-dirs and extra-lib-dirs (but if you copied the files above this shouldn't be necessary),

Any time you get

```
Missing (or bad) header file
```

check to see you copied the *.h files to mingw64\include and/or add the include folder to the PATH. Use cabal install -v3 to get verbose error messages if the problem persists.

If you get something like

```
cairo-0.13.1.0: include-dirs: /mingw64/include/freetype2 is a relative path
which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can
make paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
```

try --ghc-pkg-options="--force" (as mentioned at https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/139).

4. Get SDL. Otherwise you'll get

   configure: error: *** SDL not found! Get SDL from www.libsdl.org.
   If you already installed it, check it's in the path. If problem remains,
   please send a mail to the address that appears in ./configure --version
   indicating your platform, the version of configure script and the problem.
   Failed to install SDL-0.6.5.1

Follow the instructions in (2) to get sdl/sdl2 libraries. (See instructions here [Installing SDL on Windows for Haskell (GHC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635043/installing-sdl-on-windows-for-haskell-ghc).)

The new version helm-0.7.1 requires sdl2, but there are other dependency issues with helm-0.7.1 as of writing.  Download SDL from http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/x86_64/ (direct download link to newest version as of writing http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL-1.2.15-7-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig/download), unzip. "cabal install sdl" gives

```
* Missing (or bad) header file: SDL/SDL.h
* Missing C library: SDL
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

so we specify where the dirs are (change the name depending on where you extracted sdl to)

```
cabal install sdl --extra-include-dirs=C:/PF/sdl\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:/sdl/lib
```

If you got SDL2 (http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) (for a newer version of Helm): there is a fatal bug that hasn't been fixed in the release version. (If you don't fix it, cabal install -v3 things which depends on it will give error

```
winapifamily.h: No such file or directory
```

(["winapifamily.h: No such file or directory" when compiling SDL in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446008/winapifamily-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compiling-sdl-in-codeblocks)) Download https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/raw-file/e217ed463f25/include/SDL_platform.h, replace the file in the include folder and in C:/PF/msys64/mingw64/include/SDL2.

5. Download gtk2hs from http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs and run

the following

```
cd gtk2hs/tools
cabal install
cd ../glib
cabal install
cd ../gio
cabal install
cd ../pango
cabal install --ghc-pkg-options="--force"
```

(Maybe you have already installed glib and gio from before? I did this step because normal install of Pango caused an error for me (https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/110)

```
pango-0.13.1.0: include-dirs: /mingw64/include/freetype2 is a relative path
which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can
make paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
```

6. Once the Helm developers get things updated you should be able to do "cabal install helm" but right now there seem to be dependency issues. For me, cabal automatically tries to install helm-0.4 (probably because 0.4 didn't give upper bounds on dependencies, while newer versions do. You could try "cabal unpack"ing and deleting the upper bounds...). Then

   cabal unpack helm-0.4

Installing gives an error because "pure" got moved to Prelude. Open helm-0.4\src\FRP\Helm\Automaton.hs and change line 17:

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.), pure)
```

Now

```
cabal install
```

7. Try to compile and run a program using Helm

(This is 0.4 - look on the website for a newer sample if you tried a newer Helm)

```
import FRP.Helm
import qualified FRP.Helm.Window as Window

render :: (Int, Int) -> Element
render (w, h) = collage w h [filled red $ rect (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h)]

main :: IO ()
main = run $ fmap (fmap render) Window.dimensions
```

If you get an error about a missing .dll (sdl.dll), find it in a bin/ folder and add the folder to your PATH (or copy it to somewhere on your path).