# Trying to use igraph on Windows, but python can't load cairo

Tags: python, windows, gtk, igraph, cairo

I've been trying to use igraph in python for network analysis, but whenever I try to import igraph I get the following error:

```
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\Users\Nate\Anaconda3\libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

I followed the directions here:
[How to install cairo on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526375/how-to-install-cairo-on-windows)

to install cairo through GTK, but I'm still getting this error message. I was able to get msys64 (https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) working, and that seemed to install the one `libcairo-2.dll` and I copied it into my anaconda directory, but I couldn't find the other missing files. In the error message, you can see that anaconda recognizes the dll, but can't load it.

One step I was not able to follow from the linked instructions was `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools` then `cabal install gtk`. I added the msys64 directory to my windows path, but the `cabal` command was not recognized in the msys64 or windows command lines.

Please help this newbie if you can!

Comment: The easiest thing is to install `python-igraph` in Anaconda using `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph`. That way, the necessary `cairo` libraries will be automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vincent Traag! That worked, and was much simpler than any of the methods I had previously seen!

For anyone finding this later execute this command in the **Anaconda Powershell** to install igraph for python:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph
```

Comment: Please accept this answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.